Which workload is required to install MSTest with Build Tools 2022?
I'm setting up a CI/CD VM for building and testing .NET Framework applications.
So, I'm installing the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktopBuildTools, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.WebBuildTools and Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.TestAgent workloads, but I still cannot find MSTest.exe on my VM.
Which workload do I need to add to be able to perform automated component tests using the command line?

You probably want to install the MSTest Nuget package in to your test project.

You should also take a look at this recent (Jan '24) article Introducing the MSTest Runner – CLI, Visual Studio, & More. Although it's focussed on more recent versions of .NET it should also work for .NET Framework.

Run
winget install --id=Microsoft.VisualStudio.2022.BuildTools  -e
. Open the visual studio installer and select core testing tools from the individual packages to have the
vstest.console.exe
(successor of mstest.exe).

Thanks, guys, for helping! We found the necessary workload now.

We investigated further and found that the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TestTools.BuildTools workload is required to install VSTest.Console.exe along with Visual Studio Build Tools 2022.
